# What is the difference between a static node and a trusted node?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes

In the [docs](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/network/connecting-to-the-network.html#static-nodes-trusted-nodes-and-boot-nodes), static nodes are described as

> Geth supports a feature called static nodes if you have certain peers you always want to connect to. Static nodes are re-connected on disconnects.

There is a `<datadir>/static-nodes.json` and a `trusted-nodes.json` too.

I can't find anywhere that explains the difference though.

Comment: If using geth 1.5.2+, note the state of https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3326

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Won't add much than what you said apart from the reconnection feature !

According to [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/831) and [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/832) as you said :

> p2p.Server should be able to use a JSON file containing trusted node
>   addresses. It should try to keep those nodes connected at all times.
>   The connections should not count toward the maximum number of
>   connections.

and

> Trusted nodes are privileged: they get connected/accepted even above
>   the maximum peer count Connections to trusted nodes are reattempted
>   every once in a while (15 sec for now)

In geth [code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/5490437942967638bcc6198035315f6811febaa8/p2p/server.go#L91) you can see the comment:

```
// Trusted nodes are used as pre-configured connections which are always
// allowed to connect, even above the peer limit.
```

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, trusted nodes are nodes can be added even max peers reached
but the node won't constantly try to connect to them like they will with static nodes.

*This is the only answer I've come across so far. If anyone has any further detail, that would be awesome.*

Comment: This is proof that is correct, Taylor : https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/ns-admin#admin-addtrustedpeer