# Losing connection between nodes on private network

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, network

I have 3 nodes running on a private network.

After asking [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/peer-discovery-not-working-on-private-network), I've manually added `node1` as peer to `node2` and `node3`, so my network looks like this:

```
                 _______                    
     ---------> | node2 |
    /           |_______|
   v
 _______
| node1 |
|_______|
   ^
    \            _______
     ---------> | node3 |
                |_______|
```

I've left the nodes running through last night, but around 10 PM (BRST), `node2` and `node3` stopped listening to `node1` (`admin.peers` was empty), while `node1` was still connected to both of them (`admin.peers` contained 2 items), but not getting any interaction.

Is it possible that this is a problem with Ethereum protocol or would it be something else?

---

### Edit:

I'm running the nodes in the same physical machine, but in different VMs. Those VMs have `Ubuntu 12.04` installed.

The VMs are running over a CentOS with VMWare vCenter.

Comment: Are the clocks on your different nodes all synced to network time?

Comment: Yes, they are. In deed, they are in the same physical machine, altough they're in different VMs.

Comment: What VM system are you using andwhat is the host operating system?

Comment: @JackWinters I've edited the question...

Answer (score 7):

**Summary**

I would have expected that the bootnodes parameters would allow node 2 and node 3 to find node 1, node 2 and node 3 and then for all the nodes to retain their peer connections.

From `Henrique Barcelos`'s issue, it seems that this configuration is not stable in a private network running the nodes in a VM.

The alternative of using `static-nodes.json` does not seem to provide a stable connection.

The next configuration to try is using `trusted-nodes.json` and specifying the `--maxpeers` parameter

Below are the steps we are taking to solve the problem.

---

An interesting problem.

1. Probability wise, I would say it is highly unlikely that this is a problem with the Ethereum protocol as it is robust enough for the Internet.
2. You have stated that your time is synced to network time. This seems to be a problem regularly encountered and that is why I asked the question above.
3. Let's look at your configuration.
4. Question. Are you running any other Ethereum mainnet nodes within your private network. The reason I am asking this is that there may be a clash with the network port 30303, referring to the first link in your question.
5. From the first link in your question, you are starting up your geth instances on the different nodes with the following command:

   ```
   geth --verbosity 4 --autodag --nat any --genesis /opt/blockchain/genesis.json
    --datadir /opt/blockchain/data --networkid 4828 --port 30303 --rpc
    --rpcaddr 10.48.247.25 --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,admin
    --rpccorsdomain '*' --fast --mine --ipcdisable
   ```

   Node 1 has been set as your bootnode.
   Nodes 2 and 3 have the file /opt/blockchain/data/static-nodes.json with the following information:

   ```
   ["enode://{node1publickey}@{node1ip}:30303"]
   ```
6. The information in /opt/blockchain/data/static-nodes.json in 5. above matches the startup information in the node1 geth instance that is displayed using the admin.nodeInfo command in the node1 geth instance.

   ```
   ...
   enode: "enode://{node1publickey}@{node1ip}:30303",
   ...
   ```

   Is this correct?
7. Looking at your geth startup parameters now:

   a. You could try removing the `--nat any` parameter

   b. Your `--networkid` is unique from the mainnet "1"

   c. Your `--port 30303` should not be a problem unless you are running other mainnet Ethereum nodes within your network, and even so should not be a problem as it will be on a different IP

   d. Your `--rpcaddr` should be the IP address of each machine. Node 1 should have the node 1 IP address. Node 2 should have the node 2 IP address and node 3 should have the node 3 IP address.

   e. Your `--rpcport`, `--rpcapi` and `--rpccorsdomain` should not affect your network connectivity.

   f. You should not need the `--fast` parameter as your blockchain should be small anyway, being an internal testnet blockchain.

   g. Your `--mine` and `--ipcdisable` parameters should not affect your connectivity.
8. What I would try next is to remove the `--bootnode` parameter, and try the `/opt/blockchain/data/static-nodes.json` method in 5. above on nodes 2 and 3. Run this for a while and let's hope you don't have the connectivity dropouts. We can cross this off the list if you are still having the connectivity dropouts.

Below added 12/04/2016:

9. `Henrique Barcelos` has been using the `static-nodes.json` method for the peers to find each other, but the peer connections dropped out. I've suggesting trying `trusted-nodes.json` as these specify trusted peer nodes to connect to, and would not be blocked by the `--maxpeers` connection limits.
10. What I have found from my testing is that the `static-nodes.json` option would not connect unless I add a non-zero `--maxpeers` parameter, although `--maxpeers` is meant to default to 25.

Comment: About 4. No, I'm only running the nodes in the private network.

Comment: About 5. `node1` is the bootnode, I'm passing its enode via `--bootnodes` to `node2` and `node3`, but there is no `static-nodes.json`

Comment: About 7.a. `--nat` defaults to "any" according to the [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options)

Comment: I've added a `static-nodes.json` file in `node2` and `node3`, with an array containing the enode of `node1`. I'll leave the nodes running through the night and tomorrow I'll comment the results here (I'm at GMT-0300)

Comment: Looking forward to hearing about your results.

Comment: Apparently the connectivity problem was solved. I don't know exactly what has solved i though.

Comment: Probably, the `static-nodes.json` helped, but I can't know for sure.

Comment: Run it for a few more days and check if the connections are robust. You could then revert back to the old method of using the bootnodes and if there are disconnections, confirm that the bootnodes method does not suit your environment.

Comment: Yeah, I was planning to do something like that. Thank you for your help with this issue @BokkyPooBah

Comment: Oh no! The nodes diverged again during the weekend :/

Comment: When your nodes diverge, they never rejoin? I have been doing some further testing and found that I needed to set the --maxpeers parameter for the connection between peers to work. I'll look into the a bit more and get back to you.I have also been setting the --verbosity a bit higher than the default 3 to trace my peer connection issue.

Comment: I don't think they would rejoin any time because they were 1000 blocks away from each other. I'm currently running with verbosity=4, I've seen some messages like "peer has become unhealthy", but I don't know exactly what this means.

Comment: I'm going through the logs, the last block import was done on Apr-09 at 10:37:19 GMT-0300 (last saturday), meaning that the nodes haven't communicated with each other for almost 2 days.

Comment: And I've been looking also at testing out the trusted-nodes.json as the ignores the maxpeers limit. See  http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-node-and-a-trusted-node. You may want to test this configuration next.

Comment: This is odd because `--maxpeers` defaults to 25 and I only have 3 running nodes :/

Comment: I found that when I was using --dev --networkid xxxx --nodiscover with static-nodes.json that I could not get the peers to connect with a node rejection messages (shown when verbosity is set to 4 or 5), until I manually set --maxpeers to a non-zero number.

Comment: I'm not using `--dev`, should I be?

Comment: Your --networkid and --genesis will make your network instance unique. --help shows that --dev switches on the `Developer mode: pre-configured private network with several debugging flags`.

Comment: I've noticed more verbose logs in `--dev` mode. The nodes have behaved nicely through the night, no diverging so far.

Comment: I have just finished writing up my test results on http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2851/how-can-i-reliably-induce-a-blockchain-fork-for-testing-purposes . There are some bits there on setting `admin.verbosity(6)` to trace the P2P connection attempts.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Did you ever resolve this?  I am having the same problem and these steps have not solved it.

Comment: Where do you place `trusted-nodes.json`? Do you have to restart geth for it to use the list of enodes?