# How to test forked block on local machine?

Tags: blockchain, network, peers, chain-reorganization

Read this article [How can I reliably induce a blockchain fork for testing purposes?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2851/how-can-i-reliably-induce-a-blockchain-fork-for-testing-purposes).

Example from that thread is **outdated**, and need to be refreshed.

First my step is create initial chaindata from own genesis

```
geth --datadir=./1 init custom_genesis.json
```

custom_genesis.json

```
{
    "nonce": "0",
    "difficulty": "0x20000",
    "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
    "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "timestamp": "0x00",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x",
    "gasLimit": "0x2FEFD8",
    "alloc": {},
    "config": {
        "chainId": 15,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "200000000",
    "gasLimit": "2100000"
}
```

which successfully created but not working when started

```
nohup geth --datadir=./1 --dev --nodiscover --networkid=15 --maxpeers=10 --verbosity=4 --preload ./utils.js --port=30305 --mine --minerthreads=1 > ./1/info.log 2>&1 &
```

and result

```
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: database already contains an incompatible genesis block (have 5308cb1366d2a01a, new e5be92145a301820)
```

It is another problem, but question not in this point.

> --nodiscover

param forces to run app on autogenerated port, so usage of this param

> --port 30304

will be ignored. So adding manually nodes via param `--bootnodes` or in file `<datadir>/static-nodes.json` will not work.

Also such param

> admin.verbosity(6)

does not exist anymore.
Manually usage of `admin.addPeer` does not help, seems that nodes does not see each other and always answer `true`, even this node does not exist.( Please help anyone.

My 2 nodes runner script

```
nohup geth --datadir=./1 --dev --nodiscover --networkid=15 --maxpeers=10 --verbosity=4 --preload ./utils.js --port=30305 --mine --minerthreads=1 > ./1/info.log 2>&1 &

nohup geth --datadir=./2 --dev --nodiscover --networkid=15 --maxpeers=10 --verbosity=4 --preload ./utils.js --port=30306 --mine --minerthreads=1 > ./2/info.log 2>&1 &
```