# How to use static-nodes.json / trusted-nodes.json to prevent connection loss on private network?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ether, peers, enode

I have 2 nodes running on private network under the same network id connecting through

```
sudo geth --identity "testpython manage.py runserver  0.0.0.0:8001" --networkid 1100 --mine --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport 8544 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,web3" --port 30304 --ipcpath ~/.ethereum/geth.ipc --genesis /home/user/genesis.json --datadir /home/user/genesis console privatenet 2>/home/user/genesis/log_output5
```

In one node and in other with different ports. It has same genesis.json and connected to the same network.
When i connect via,

> admin.addPeer(nodeUrl)

It will show the connection in `admin.peers` and in few seconds it will go off in both the nodes. it keep connecting and disconnecting between the nodes. and in `admin.peers` remoteAddress port is coming as `59823` though I have given `30305` port.

```
localAddress: "192.168.15.69:30304",
remoteAddress: "192.168.15.71:59823"
```

I felt this is causing me not to do `node to node ether transaction`. once node to node transaction has happened. after that i couldnot.

I read in other links that static-nodes.json / trusted-nodes.json may help in having stable connection. please help me

1. How to have stable connection
2. If we use static-nodes.json / trusted-nodes.json , how to use and which one to use. syntax please
3. How to do transactions in one node and mining from another node?

[Losing connection between nodes on private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2727/losing-connection-between-nodes-on-private-network)

Answer (score 8):

### Data format

```
[
      "enode://f4642fa65af50cfdea8fa7414a5def7bb7991478b768e296f5e4a54e8b995de102e0ceae2e826f293c481b5325f89be6d207b003382e18a8ecba66fbaf6416c0@33.4.2.1:30303",
      "enode://pubkey@ip:port"
]
```

You can configure permanent static nodes by putting something like the following into `<datadir>/static-nodes.json`

**Common problems with connectivity**

Sometimes you just can't get connected. The most common reasons are:

1. Your local time might be incorrect. An accurate clock is required to participate in the Ethereum network. Check your OS for how to resync your clock (example `sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov`) because even 12 seconds too fast can lead to 0 peers.
2. Some firewall configurations can prevent UDP traffic from flowing. You can use the static nodes feature or `admin.addPeer()` on the console to configure connections by hand.

Sources:
1. https://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide/blob/master/source/network/connecting-to-the-network.rst#static-nodes-trusted-nodes-and-boot-nodes

Answer (score 0):

Geth also supports a feature called static nodes if you have certain peers you always want to connect to. Static nodes are re-connected on disconnects. You can configure permanent static nodes by putting something like the following into <datadir>/geth/static-nodes.json:

```
[
  "enode://f4642fa65af50cfdea8fa7414a5def7bb7991478b768e296f5e4a54e8b995de102e0ceae2e826f293c481b5325f89be6d207b003382e18a8ecba66fbaf6416c0@33.4.2.1:30303",
  "enode://pubkey@ip:port"
]
```

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/peer-to-peer