# How to connect 2 nodes without admin.addPeer()?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

So, I started 2 nodes on my private net using geth, with custom genesis file, different port numbers, all how it was supposed to be. In one instance I added the    `admin.nodeInfo.enode` of the other and two nodes were perfectly in sync. I mined on one and the second had the same block number as the first. Brilliant. However, after restart the nodes were not peers anymore and I had to type `admin.addPeer()` again in order to sync them. Is there a way to sync the nodes without manually adding the peers?

To clarify, I did not use the `--nodiscover` flag so I think there should be some way the first node to discover second wtihout manual typing.

I know you can sync two nodes without `admin.addPeer()` if you declare the `admin.nodeInfo.enode` of the other in `static-nodes.json` located in the data dir of the first. But that also requiers manual entering. I want to know if there is another, simpler way.

Comment: You would use either a bootnode or a static node list: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/how-to-use-static-nodes-json-trusted-nodes-json-to-prevent-connection-loss-on