# How can I deploy a contract with reference to a library contract without using a graphical user interface like Browser Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, remix, library

I am using Solidity Browser to deploy a contract due to [from Library contract method failing #2831](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2831) issue. On this following answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9181/4575 I have guided to use Solidity Browser as (Please note that this solution works.):

> I connected Solidity Browser to my local private node by clicking on
> the block icon and selecting Web3 Provider. I then clicked on Create
> to deploy the contract above to the blockchain.

I am using Solidity Browser on my server, and it is difficult to do this process using a graphical user interface, due to my ssh connection.

[Q] Is it possible to deploy a contract without using graphical user interface via Solidity Browser? or is there any other solution?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. Browser solidity is a great development environment, but it doesn't make any sense to use it without a GUI. If you want to compile on a remote sever, use solc.

Comment: I was using solc all the time but I face with the problem I mention on my first sentences (You can reach the question here: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9178/4575) and Solidity Browser allow me to fix this problem. Is there anyway to over come this problem on solc?

Comment: By using solc compiler can I deploy contracts to my private blockchain network? @TjadenHess

Comment: you can use mist wallet as well to deploy your contracts.

Comment: @HimanshuPandey It doesn't solve the problem, it's another GUI basically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Summary

To deploy your library and contract code using `geth`, you will have to:

1. Deploy your `LinkedList` library code and note the address it is deployed to.
2. Replace the `__LinkedList___...___` text in your `Array` code with the `LinkedLibrary` deployment address and deploy the code.

Some other alternatives:

1. Create an SSH tunnel between your remote server and your local machine so you can access your remote server's `geth` RPC port from your local machine. Then use Browser Solidity on your local machine to connect to your local machine port which is a proxy for your remote server's `geth` RPC port - see [How can I expose Geth's RPC server to external connections?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3163/how-can-i-expose-geths-rpc-server-to-external-connections)
2. Set up your local machine's `geth` instance to be a peer to your remote server's `geth` instance. You can then use Browser Solidity to interact with your local machine's `geth` instance and your actions will be mirrored on your remote server. See [Losing connection between nodes on private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2727/losing-connection-between-nodes-on-private-network) and search for **private network** on this site.

---

#### Update With Source Code Provided In Comments Below

Here is the source code from the link below, unaltered except for the `pragma` statement and the addition of `constant` to the `test_callstack()` function:

```
library LinkedList {
  uint80 constant None = uint80(0); // NULL.

  struct data {
    uint256 head;
    Node[100]  n;
    uint    size;
    uint    insert_number;
    uint    buffer_size;
  }

  struct Node {
    string  data;
    address owner;
    uint    own;
    uint    prev;
    uint    next;
  }

  function construct_me(data storage self){
    self.n[0].own      = 0;
    self.n[0].next     = 0;
    self.n[0].prev     = 0;
    self.head          = 0;

    self.insert_number = self.size = 1;

    self.buffer_size   = 100;
  }
}

contract owned {
  address  public owner;
  function owned() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
  function ownerOnly() {
    if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
  }
  modifier onlyOwner {
     if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
          _;
  }
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
    owner = newOwner;
  }
}

contract Array is owned {
  using LinkedList for LinkedList.data;
  using LinkedList for LinkedList.Node;
  LinkedList.data list;

  function Array(){
    if( test_callstack() != 1 ) throw;
    list.construct_me();
  }

  function test_callstack() constant returns ( int ){ return 1; }
}
```

I've saved the source code above into `Contract.sol`.

I use the following statement to assign the flattened source code to a variable (reference https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2610/1268):

```
Iota:DeployLibrary user$ echo "var myContractSource='`$HOME/bin/stripCrLf Contract.sol`'"
var myContractSource="library LinkedList { uint80 constant None = uint80(0);  struct data { uint256 head;  Node[100] n;  uint size; uint insert_number; uint buffer_size; } struct Node { string data;  address owner;  uint own;  uint prev; uint next;  } function construct_me(data storage self){  self.n[0].own = 0; self.n[0].next = 0; self.n[0].prev = 0; self.head = 0; self.insert_number = self.size = 1;  self.buffer_size = 100; }}contract owned {  address public owner; function owned() { owner = msg.sender; } function ownerOnly() { if (msg.sender != owner) throw; } modifier onlyOwner { if (msg.sender != owner) throw; _; } function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner { owner = newOwner; }}contract Array is owned { using LinkedList for LinkedList.data; using LinkedList for LinkedList.Node; LinkedList.data list; function Array(){  if( test_callstack() != 1 ) throw;  list.construct_me(); } function test_callstack() constant returns ( int ){ return 1; }}"
```

I copied the line above into my clipboard and pasted it into a `--dev` geth instance:

```
> var myContractSource="library LinkedList { uint80 constant None = uint80(0);  struct data { uint256 head;  Node[100] n;  uint size; uint insert_number; uint buffer_size; } struct Node { string data;  address owner;  uint own;  uint prev; uint next;  } function construct_me(data storage self){  self.n[0].own = 0; self.n[0].next = 0; self.n[0].prev = 0; self.head = 0; self.insert_number = self.size = 1;  self.buffer_size = 100; }}contract owned {  address public owner; function owned() { owner = msg.sender; } function ownerOnly() { if (msg.sender != owner) throw; } modifier onlyOwner { if (msg.sender != owner) throw; _; } function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner { owner = newOwner; }}contract Array is owned { using LinkedList for LinkedList.data; using LinkedList for LinkedList.Node; LinkedList.data list; function Array(){  if( test_callstack() != 1 ) throw;  list.construct_me(); } function test_callstack() constant returns ( int ){ return 1; }}"
undefined
```

I compiled the source code:

```
> var myContractCompiled=web3.eth.compile.solidity(myContractSource);
undefined
```

To check the available ABIs, I type the following:

```
> myContractCompiled
myContractCompiled
{
  Array: {
    code: "0x6060604081905260008054600160a060020a0319166c01000000000000000000000000338102041781557f14ea1cf8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008252600160645273__LinkedList____________________________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",
    info: {
      abiDefinition: [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}],
      compilerOptions: "--combined-json bin,abi,userdoc,devdoc --add-std --optimize",
      compilerVersion: "0.4.4",
      developerDoc: {
        methods: {}
      },
      language: "Solidity",
      languageVersion: "0.4.4",
      source: "library LinkedList { uint80 constant None = uint80(0);  struct data { uint256 head;  Node[100] n;  uint size; uint insert_number; uint buffer_size; } struct Node { string data;  address owner;  uint own;  uint prev; uint next;  } function construct_me(data storage self){  self.n[0].own = 0; self.n[0].next = 0; self.n[0].prev = 0; self.head = 0; self.insert_number = self.size = 1;  self.buffer_size = 100; }}contract owned {  address public owner; function owned() { owner = msg.sender; } function ownerOnly() { if (msg.sender != owner) throw; } modifier onlyOwner { if (msg.sender != owner) throw; _; } function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner { owner = newOwner; }}contract Array is owned { using LinkedList for LinkedList.data; using LinkedList for LinkedList.Node; LinkedList.data list; function Array(){  if( test_callstack() != 1 ) throw;  list.construct_me(); } function test_callstack() constant returns ( int ){ return 1; }}",
      userDoc: {
        methods: {}
      }
    }
  },
  LinkedList: {
    code: "0x6060604052605c8060106000396000f36504044633f3de50606060405260e060020a600035046314ea1cf881146024575b6007565b600060036004803591820183905560058201839055810182905590815560016101f582018190556101f682015560646101f79091015500",
    info: {
      abiDefinition: [{...}],
      compilerOptions: "--combined-json bin,abi,userdoc,devdoc --add-std --optimize",
      compilerVersion: "0.4.4",
      developerDoc: {
        methods: {}
      },
      language: "Solidity",
      languageVersion: "0.4.4",
      source: "library LinkedList { uint80 constant None = uint80(0);  struct data { uint256 head;  Node[100] n;  uint size; uint insert_number; uint buffer_size; } struct Node { string data;  address owner;  uint own;  uint prev; uint next;  } function construct_me(data storage self){  self.n[0].own = 0; self.n[0].next = 0; self.n[0].prev = 0; self.head = 0; self.insert_number = self.size = 1;  self.buffer_size = 100; }}contract owned {  address public owner; function owned() { owner = msg.sender; } function ownerOnly() { if (msg.sender != owner) throw; } modifier onlyOwner { if (msg.sender != owner) throw; _; } function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner { owner = newOwner; }}contract Array is owned { using LinkedList for LinkedList.data; using LinkedList for LinkedList.Node; LinkedList.data list; function Array(){  if( test_callstack() != 1 ) throw;  list.construct_me(); } function test_callstack() constant returns ( int ){ return 1; }}",
      userDoc: {
        methods: {}
      }
    }
  },
  owned: {
    code: "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",
    info: {
      abiDefinition: [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}],
      compilerOptions: "--combined-json bin,abi,userdoc,devdoc --add-std --optimize",
      compilerVersion: "0.4.4",
      developerDoc: {
        methods: {}
      },
      language: "Solidity",
      languageVersion: "0.4.4",
      source: "library LinkedList { uint80 constant None = uint80(0);  struct data { uint256 head;  Node[100] n;  uint size; uint insert_number; uint buffer_size; } struct Node { string data;  address owner;  uint own;  uint prev; uint next;  } function construct_me(data storage self){  self.n[0].own = 0; self.n[0].next = 0; self.n[0].prev = 0; self.head = 0; self.insert_number = self.size = 1;  self.buffer_size = 100; }}contract owned {  address public owner; function owned() { owner = msg.sender; } function ownerOnly() { if (msg.sender != owner) throw; } modifier onlyOwner { if (msg.sender != owner) throw; _; } function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner { owner = newOwner; }}contract Array is owned { using LinkedList for LinkedList.data; using LinkedList for LinkedList.Node; LinkedList.data list; function Array(){  if( test_callstack() != 1 ) throw;  list.construct_me(); } function test_callstack() constant returns ( int ){ return 1; }}",
      userDoc: {
        methods: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `myContractCompiled.Array.code` contains the text `__LinkedList__...___`. This will need to be replaced with the address (without the `0x` prefix) of the deployed `LinkedList` library.

Deploy the `LinkedList` library:

```
> var myLinkedListLib = web3.eth.contract(myContractCompiled.LinkedList.info.abiDefinition);
undefined
> var linkedListLib = myLinkedListLib.new({
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0],
    data: myContractCompiled.LinkedList.code, gas: 400000},
    function(e, contract) {
      if (!e) {
        if (!contract.address) {
          console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " +
            contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
        } else {
          console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
          console.log(contract);
        }
    }
})
Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: 0x420908d8f22649542d532f256dff3ae5a7b473c68c68274d8c83ba9539f6d0e1 waiting to be mined...
Contract mined! Address: 0xc6fa3b899c8840585e706f90d1e43c7229cf9d5d
```

Let's check the gas used:

```
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x420908d8f22649542d532f256dff3ae5a7b473c68c68274d8c83ba9539f6d0e1")
{
  blockHash: "0xff0ba9946211a9d3b0824e5758d148334ef1de6689c8fba70916e52bd35e2167",
  blockNumber: 2370,
  contractAddress: "0xc6fa3b899c8840585e706f90d1e43c7229cf9d5d",
  cumulativeGasUsed: 78469,
  from: "0x000d1009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e",
  gasUsed: 78469,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0x9c7f63caedfd133826622a2872907fc52ede05cc9c0b644bfadf92bcfa5aaed5",
  to: null,
  transactionHash: "0x420908d8f22649542d532f256dff3ae5a7b473c68c68274d8c83ba9539f6d0e1",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Replace the `__LinkedList__*` text with the above address in the Array contract code.

```
> var arrayCode = myContractCompiled.Array.code.replace(/__LinkedList__+/g, "c6fa3b899c8840585e706f90d1e43c7229cf9d5d")
undefined
> arrayCode
"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"
```

Deploy `Array` with the modified code:

```
> var myArray = web3.eth.contract(myContractCompiled.Array.info.abiDefinition);
undefined
> var array = myArray.new({
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0],
    data: arrayCode, gas: 400000},
    function(e, contract) {
      if (!e) {
        if (!contract.address) {
          console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " +
            contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
        } else {
          console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
          console.log(contract);
        }
    }
})
Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: 0x2652d322915ec6f3668a701b5ef41c09cf5aa93de0fd7c18f8de9250a9811505 waiting to be mined...
undefined
...
Contract mined! Address: 0x036a55eb6419b503692eeedd3c446f9252642001

I0103 19:47:37.967249 miner/worker.go:516] commit new work on block 1504 with 1 txs & 0 uncles. Took 4.177908ms
...
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x2652d322915ec6f3668a701b5ef41c09cf5aa93de0fd7c18f8de9250a9811505")
{
  blockHash: "0xb6da4bcb8349333f023ed9fc41c47275e27bd1cc446c130842ee8eda51323ee9",
  blockNumber: 2429,
  contractAddress: "0x036a55eb6419b503692eeedd3c446f9252642001",
  cumulativeGasUsed: 227373,
  from: "0x000d1009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e",
  gasUsed: 227373,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0x4fe08613be0eb3475f25cec740b723d8124161bc36093cf2064543ef3e6cdd45",
  to: null,
  transactionHash: "0x2652d322915ec6f3668a701b5ef41c09cf5aa93de0fd7c18f8de9250a9811505",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Let's test your function:

```
> array.test_callstack()
1
```

Note: The code above requires the `homesteadBlock` configuration to be specified in your `genesis.json` if you are deploying your library calling contract to a private/dev network - see [How to call Library Function from a Contract? => [error] The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount. undefined](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9178/how-to-call-library-function-from-a-contract-error-the-contract-code-could).

Comment: OP is asking for solution inside `browser-solidity` without the GUI. Chicken or Egg? :D

Comment: Should I increase the gas value which is `400000` ?  because  my contract's gas required is much larger.

Comment: Increase it to a large value, e.g., 4,000,000 . Then use `eth.getTransactionReceipt({txhash})` to find out the exact number of gas required to deploy your code. Then just use a number slightly larger than the required gas.

Comment: Post your code or a link to it and I can check it for you, or suggest a few other alternatives.

Comment: When I deploy same contract through Solidity: Transaction cost is 2046298 gas and it mines.  Later I gave slightly higher gas value inside solc as you suggested. Everything works but the transaction never mines and nothing happens after (`waiting to be mined...`) output inside geth.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/3496d374fa0b729d9ca78c93729714ce Please note that I am deploying on my private blockchain network. Thank you @BokkyPooBah.

Comment: I've deployed your code to my `--dev` blockchain successfully - updated details in my answer.

Comment: `--dev` is not required. You just need the `homesteadBlock` specified in the `genesis.json` if you are using a private dev network - see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9178/how-to-call-library-function-from-a-contract-error-the-contract-code-could as this is required to enable the calling of the library functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51138/discussion-between-avatar-and-bokkypoobah).

Comment: Your solution works perfectly fine. What if I have import `"./LinkedList.sol";import "./ReceiptLib.sol";` on my contract what should I do? @BokkyPooBah

Comment: `var myContractCompiled=web3.eth.compile.solidity(myContractSource)` gives following error: 
`Error: The method eth_compileSolidity does not exist/is not available`. I think this function is not in use (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3793) and this answer needs to be updated for the latest geth version. @The Officious BokkyPooBah