# debug.traceTransaction(<transactionID>) returns a empty structLogs: []. What might be the reason?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

On the comments here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6011/4575

> For a transaction to a contract, the contract vm instructions will
>   execute and the steps are shown in the status.structLogs, so
>   status.structLogs.length will always be > 0. For a transaction to
>   another non-contract account, status.structLogs.length will be 0.

I have called a function on my contract account:

```
> myContractInstance.createCluster(128, "hello" , {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 1999999 } )
"0x93705fa9c6d240351045ed33505ec714965ce3698b879c94a43ac9b96a9c30b9"

> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x93705fa9c6d240351045ed33505ec714965ce3698b879c94a43ac9b96a9c30b9")
{
  blockHash: "0x72b97812c160c4a1b4995925d31648df1cfe0a391a3ec4a9a9d6f2ffd7cccf17",
  blockNumber: 1029605,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 22168,
  from: "0x75a4c787c5c18c587b284a904165ff06a269b48c",
  gasUsed: 22168,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0x4239343552f216d8d2063c90364340b875590fb85b24218bf3e94ee3cdf8f916",
  to: "0xaf9cac40ab2bb30ff54bba692ed4eb2a9cc46c24",
  transactionHash: "0x93705fa9c6d240351045ed33505ec714965ce3698b879c94a43ac9b96a9c30b9",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

**[Q]** After transaction has been deployed, debug.traceTransaction() returns a empty `structLogs: []`. What might be the reason?

```
> status = web3.debug.traceTransaction("0x93705fa9c6d240351045ed33505ec714965ce3698b879c94a43ac9b96a9c30b9")
{
  gas: 22616,
  returnValue: "",
  structLogs: []
}
```

Please note that I have followed following guide: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11031/4575. I guess the issue is related how I imported the libraries. When libraries and the contract on the same file I was able to deploy my contract but when I have used `import "localPath/LinkedList.sol";` the problem I mentioned occurred.

Comment: I just checked on etherscan.io for mainnet, kovan, and ropsten. The transaction  hash you reference doesn't show up on any of those chains. Are you on a private chain or something?

Comment: Oh I am sorry to mention, yes I am on private chain. @Thomas Jay Rush