# Possible Library Linkage problem on deployed contract at `remix-alpha`, that actually works on JavaScript mode

Tags: solidity, remix

I guess this error is related to following [closed issue](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/issues/1110#issuecomment-372678216), which still exists. The issue closed recommending us to use [remix-alpha](http://remix-alpha.ethereum.org), but `remix-alpha` still has the same error or I might be doing something wrong.

**=>** Is there anyone else facing with similar problem?

Deployed file names:

```
Lib.sol         # Library contract //uses around 1,600,000 GAS to be deployed.
myContract.sol  # Main contract    //uses around 3,400,000 GAS to be deployed.
```

I have tested my contract and it works perfectly fine on [populus](https://github.com/ethereum/populus) and remix's `JavaScript VM` mode. So there is no issue on the contract's code and its implementation.

But whenever I deployed my contract on the `remix-alpha`; and tested my code on the deployed code as on `Web3 Provide mode`, if there is a call to Library function, the function call crashes (`thrown`) at that point.

**I really don't know what causes this problem. This error is pretty annoying costing me hours and ether for each deployment, and facing contract does not work as it should be.**

As simplified, I have an emptied Library function call:

Lib.sol:

```
/* Simple Library function */
function constructCluster() public {

}
```

When there is a call to that function; the function call is `reverted()`.

myContract.sol: `cluster.constructCluster(); //Contract is reverted()`

**[Q]** Is there anyway to fix this issue? I am out ot options. The only solution comes to my mind to merge main contact and Library contract but when I merge them I face with following error: `SolcError: InternalCompilerError: Static memory load of more than 32 bytes requested.`

=> Instead of using remix browser, if I deploy my contract from `geth-console` would it help to fix the problem?

---

*Please note that:* I have tried shorten the contract's name and deploy at http://remix.ethereum.org/. But the exact same contract gives same linkage problem on `JavaScript VM mode` at remix.ethereum.org that actually works at https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity 's `JavaScript VM mode`.

Comment: Didn't you mention a problem with long filenames? The link you provide says name "lib.sol" works and you use the same name. Did you accidentally write the new working filename in this question?

Comment: I assume problem might be related with something else. I tried short files names, and it somehow used works at remix.org. But now, the exactly same contract works on remix-alpha's `JavaScript VM` mode but does not work (failing on Library function call) on remix's `JavaScript VM mode`.  Hence since it now does not work on remix's `JavaScript VM mode`, its deployed version on `Web3 Provide mode` also does not work even I use shorter files names. @Lauri Peltonen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please note that**, this is an alternative solution to deploy your contract using `geth-console` and `solc` compiler. I was not able to fix the bug or find its reason on the `remix browser`.

In my opinion using `geth-console` and `solc` compiler to deploy contract our best option. I tried following solution and everything work all fine, I did not face with and Library linkage issue. **Hence, `remix` may have some unsolved errors/issues related to Library linkage so I do not recommend it to use it if you have any library contract**.

Following guide is followed ([How can I deploy a contract with reference to a library contract without using a graphical user interface like Browser Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11030/how-can-i-deploy-a-contract-with-reference-to-a-library-contract-without-using-a)). Some updates has been made for the `geth` version (`Geth/v1.8.0-unstable`).

```
$ solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52.Darwin.appleclang
```

---

myContract.sol:

```
library Lib {
    struct clusterData {
        bool isRunning; 
    }
  function constructCluster(clusterData storage self){
      self.isRunning         = true;
  }
}

contract Array {
  using Lib for Lib.clusterData;
  address[] clusterAddresses;
  mapping(address => Lib.clusterData) clusterContract;

  function registerCluster(){
     clusterContract[msg.sender].constructCluster();
     clusterAddresses.push(msg.sender);
  }

 function getClusterAddresses() public view
    returns (address[])
   {
    return clusterAddresses;
   }
}
```

---

```
$ echo "var testOutput=`solc --optimize --combined-json abi,bin,interface myContract.sol`" > myContract.js
```

Open `geth-console`.

```
loadScript("myContract.js")

var myLib = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(testOutput.contracts["myContract.sol:Lib"].abi))

var linkedListLib = myLib.new({ from: eth.accounts[0], data: "0x" + testOutput.contracts["myContract.sol:Lib"].bin, gas: 4700000},
  function (e, contract) {
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Lib mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
  }
);
Lib mined! address: 0xa766ab8683e7899f52c28484dd94e50cf4ad7747 transactionHash: 0xc7fb4550eb8c546cc9134a2771bb21d58a67ead4a6c62f51400323c777e7c097
```

First wait `Lib.sol` to be deployed. Then replace the `__myContract.sol:Lib__________________*` text with the above address removing `0x` at the beginning.

```
var arrayCode = testOutput.contracts["myContract.sol:myContract"].bin.replace(/__myContract.sol:Lib__________________+/g, "a766ab8683e7899f52c28484dd94e50cf4ad7747")

var myArray = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(testOutput.contracts["myContract.sol:Array"].abi));

var myContract = myArray.new({ from: eth.accounts[0], data: "0x" + arrayCode, gas: 4700000},
  function (e, contract) {
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('myContract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
  }
);
myContract mined! address: 0xaa88aff84b259219c789e72a36aeaf0c57f98089 transactionHash: 0x9b52d196c47e5bf1add01ef9c35cff35f48baabf36313c787e27cc1caaff063e
```