# Add Two peer from two different machine into one machine

Tags: private-blockchain

I have created three node on three different machines. I have used same genesis file for all three nodes. Here is my screenshots of nodes
**Node-1**

[image: Node-1 information]

Similarly, I have set up two more node on two different machine. 
[image: Node-2 information]

[image: Node-3 information]

I have created accounts on each node and started mining in the first node by miner.start(1). After that, I have added peers such as node-2 and node-3 into node-1 by 
"enode://5a5532c24bed8f6317a69dd7525a918b3fe9efb14be3733f33741bdff255bc5090c2b21187d3ff79478e44d3ec8da138e8e25e0c7135909bc3ce6b9c7238e0df@172.16.3.233:30303?discport=0"

"enode://d9bdfd131a5d70e2551dccabe7ff5664b46a9a214dad493e00687cc19a7e94d1cd2b8ae9028dedc9aef578b075d031ab6d86c4579f1dcf5d60a4bb1a29b12942@172.16.3.234:30303?discport=0"

Now,the issue is that when I type admin.peers, it only shows one peer which is node-1. Like this
[image: Admin.peer peer details]

Sometimes, it shows both the peers and sometimes, admin.peers return empty.Please help me out to understand this.

Comment: How did you add peers, what commands you used?. Try this option [solution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2727/losing-connection-between-nodes-on-private-network?noredirect=1&lq=1) ?

Comment: I have added the following two peers from two different machines into third machine by the command admin.addPeer("enode://5a5532c24bed8f6317a69dd7525a918b3fe9efb14be3733f33741bdff255bc5090c2b21187d3ff79478e44d3ec8da138e8e25e0c7135909bc3ce6b9c7238e0df@172.16.3.233:30303?discport=0")

admin.addPeer("enode://d9bdfd131a5d70e2551dccabe7ff5664b46a9a214dad493e00687cc19a7e94d1cd2b8ae9028dedc9aef578b075d031ab6d86c4579f1dcf5d60a4bb1a29b12942@172.16.3.234:30303?discport=0") . I shows two peers entry sometimes and shows blank most of the time.