# how to make the list of peers permanent on a private network

Tags: go-ethereum

I have joined a private network and it works fine when I add the peers with `admin.addPeer` but I have to add the peers every time I launch geth.

How can I make the list of peers permanent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several categories of nodes in Ethereum:

**1. Bootnodes**

These are nodes used for bootstrapping purposes, and which are hard-coded into your Geth binary. The hard-coded values can be overridden using the `--bootnodes` option when running Geth from the command line. Alternatively, the hard-codings can be changed by editing the Geth code and rebuilding from source. In your case, it sounds like these hard-codings haven't been updated with any of the nodes in your private network, which is why you can't connect straight out of the box.

**2. Static nodes**

These are peers you always want to connect to. They're not necessarily boot nodes. You can set them either by using `admin.addPeer` command, as you've found, or by editing your `<datadir>/static-nodes.json` file, as described in the [official documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#static-nodes). **In your case, I'd recommend editing this file.**

**3. Trusted nodes**

Slightly different to static nodes, in that connections to these nodes don't count towards the total, limited connection count. As explained [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-node-and-a-trusted-node).

Comment: I looked into p2p directory in the source code, but I didn't find hardcoded server IP addresses for the bootnodes. Do you know what is the file name where these IPs are hardcoded?

Comment: Should it be `<datadir>/geth/static-nodes.json` as mentioned in the docs you linked? This directory contains folders `chaindata`, `lightchaindata`, `nodes`, and files `transactions.rlp`, `LOCK`, `nodekey`

Answer (score 1):

you could when launching `geth`  specify the different nodes separated by commas as follow :

```
geth --bootnodes enode://pubkey1@ip1:port1,enode://pubkey2@ip2:port2,enode://pubkey3@ip3:port3
```

More details : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network

to automate the task you could create a batch file in windows or a script in linux

Comment: I make a comment now long after the answer because since at least last September  (when I last tried it) this would not work, the node would expect a bootnode answer and on getting a (valid) node answer it would drop the peer. Took me forever to debug this one.